# How to install only JRE from Java 12 into docker image?

Tags: java, docker, openjdk-12

Everyone!

I'm trying to minimize my docker images which has to run java apps.
With Java 8 and previous versions, I had an option to install only JRE into the image. But since Java 9 was released, I've lost such option. Seems, they don't provide separate distribution for JRE anymore.

Probably, someone of you had some experience which might be helpful.

Cheers & have a nice day!

Comment: Make your own with `jlink`.

Comment: Have you tried to use alpine linux based image?

Comment: @ToniNurmi yes I have, alpine contains full JDK

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thank you. I will take a look at jlink

Comment: Since java 9 and the introduction of [project jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start), you only add your required java modules, thus minimizing your docker image even more. So I suggest you investigate which modules you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using default-jre. It's really easy to install from the apt package manager.